Integrating x^4 using the integral definition
The task is to integrate $x^4$ in the interval [1,4] using the definition in 3 steps and the partition $P_n:= \langle 4^{\frac{0}{n}},4^{\frac{1}{n}},...,4^{\frac{n}{n}} \rangle$. First of all the upper and lower sum have to be calculated, but I'm already struggling here not being sure whether it is correct what I did.
$f(x) = x^4$ is monotonically increasing. Thus we have:
$$M_k = sup\{f(x) | t_{k-1} \le x \le t_k\} = f(t_k) = t_k^4$$
and $$m_k = inf\{f(x) | t_{k-1} \le x \le t_k\} = f(t_{k-1}) = t_{k-1}^4.$$
We follow for the upper sum:
$$O(f,P_n) = \sum \limits_{k=1}^{n}M_k(t_k - t_{k-1})$$
$$=\sum \limits_{k=1}^{n}t_k^4(t_k-t_{k-1})= \sum \limits_{k=1}^{n}4^{\frac{4k}{n}}(4^{\frac{k}{n}} - 4^{\frac{k-1}{n}})$$
$$=\sum \limits_{k=1}^{n}(4^{\frac{5k}{n}} - 4^{\frac{5k-1}{n}}) =\sum \limits_{k=1}^{n}(4^\frac{5}{n})^k(1 - 4^\frac{-1}{n})$$
$$= (1 - 4^\frac{-1}{n}) \cdot \sum \limits_{k=1}^{n}(4^\frac{5}{n})^k = (1 - 4^\frac{-1}{n}) \cdot \sum \limits_{k=0}^{n}(4^\frac{5}{n})^k -1 + 4^\frac{-1}{n}$$
Using the geometric series I get
$$(1 - 4^\frac{-1}{n}) \cdot \frac{1-(4^\frac{5}{n})^{n+1}}{1-4^{\frac{5}{n}}} -1 + 4^\frac{-1}{n}$$
Assuming that I didn't calculate anything wrong, how could this term be simplified more? There is the hint that $\lim_{x \to 0} \frac{a^x -1}{x} = log \; a$ for a > 0 can be used, but where?

Since
$\sum \limits_{k=m}^{n} a^k = a^m \cdot \sum \limits_{k=0}^{n-m} a^k =   a^m \cdot \frac{1-a^{n-m+1}}{1-a}$
You can write $\sum \limits_{k=1}^{n}(4^\frac{5}{n})^k$ as:
$\sum \limits_{k=1}^{n}(4^\frac{5}{n})^k = 4^\frac{5}{n} \cdot \frac{1-(4^\frac{5}{n})^{n}}{1-4^{\frac{5}{n}}} = \left( 1- 4^5\right) \cdot \frac{4^\frac{5}{n}}{1-4^{\frac{5}{n}}}$
Hope this helps.
Edit:
You get:
$\begin{align} 
O(f,P_n) &= (1 - 4^\frac{-1}{n}) \cdot \left( 1- 4^5\right) \cdot \frac{4^\frac{5}{n}}{1-4^{\frac{5}{n}}}\\
&= (1 - 4^\frac{-1}{n}) \cdot \frac{-n}{-n} \cdot \left( 1- 4^5\right)\cdot \frac{4^\frac{5}{n}}{1-4^{\frac{5}{n}}} \\
&= \frac{(1 - 4^\frac{-1}{n}) }{\frac{-1}{n}}\cdot -\left( 1- 4^5\right)\cdot 4^\frac{5}{n} \cdot \frac{\frac{1}{n}}{1-4^{\frac{5}{n}}} \\
&= \frac{(1 - 4^\frac{-1}{n}) }{\frac{1}{-n}}\cdot \frac{-\left( 1- 4^5\right)}{5}\cdot 4^\frac{5}{n} \cdot \frac{5 \cdot \frac{1}{n}}{1-4^{\frac{5}{n}}}  \\
&= \frac{(1 - 4^\frac{-1}{n}) }{\frac{1}{-n}}\cdot \frac{\left(4^5-1\right)}{5}\cdot 4^\frac{5}{n} \cdot \frac{\frac{5}{n}}{1-4^{\frac{5}{n}}}
\end{align}$
The trick here is to see that $n \to \infty \implies 1/n = x \to 0.$
By taking the limit, you get:
$\lim_{n \to \infty} \frac{(1 - 4^\frac{-1}{n})}{\frac{-1}{n}} = \lim_{x \to 0} \frac{(1 - 4^x)}{x} = -\log(4) $
Using the same trick :
$\lim_{n \to \infty}  \frac{ \frac{ 5}{n } }{1-4^{ \frac{5}{n} } } = \frac{1}{-\log(4)}$
$\lim_{n \to \infty} 4^\frac{5}{n} = 1$
So by taking the limit, everything cancels out except the desired result

Okay Thanks, that's a good trick with the geometric series! Then I get above: $(1 - 4^\frac{-1}{n}) \cdot \left( 1- 4^5\right) \cdot \frac{4^\frac{5}{n}}{1-4^{\frac{5}{n}}}$
But how could I use the hint $lim_{x \to 0} \frac{a^x - 1}{x} = 0$ ?

Wow that's a great way you did it! However the desired result should be $\frac{1}{5}(4^5-1)$, and I'm wondering where to get the factor $\frac{1}{5}$ mhm, do you have an idea maybe?

Nah i did something wrong, I got something like $lim_{x \to 0} \frac{a^x - 1}{a^x} =0$ which is different than your hint. I'll get back to you

Yeah I noticed that as well while going through it, thought we had it :D Okay thx!

When taking $(1 - 4^{-\frac{1}{n}})$ and dividing the whole term by $-\frac{1}{n}$ and adding it to the enumerator, I get $log ; 4 \cdot (4^5 - 1)$, however would still have to deal with $-\frac{1}{n} \cdot \frac{4^\frac{5}{n}}{1 - 4^\frac{5}{n}}$

yes, add $\frac{5}{5}$ and you'll get the right form for the last part, and there comes the desired 1/5

That's great and so interesting, thanks so much! I'm wondering how you did that so quickly? Did you try out a little bit moving around terms and so on?

Hey @anton, there is still a minus issue because of $\frac{\frac{5}{n}}{1-4^{\frac{5}{n}}}$, and it should be $\frac{-\frac{5}{n}}{1-4^{\frac{5}{n}}}$. Do you happen to know why? I couldn't figure it out.

Before you do the manipulations, you have $(1-4^5) \cdot \frac{-n}{-n}$. One of the $-n$ would go to $(1-4^{\frac{-1}{n}})$ and for the other, you would seperate the minus from $-n$ and give it to $(1-4^5)$ so you would have $(4^5-1)$ and you will be left with a $+n$ which would give you $\frac{\frac{5}{n}}{1-4^\frac{5}{n}}$ which would be good. So there isn't a minus issue.

Ahh I saw that now Thanks! Sorry was kinda blindfolded...
